# Google Maps API MapView doesn't fully load

Tags: android, api, google-maps, xamarin, google-play

As I open my app, the only thing the MapView shows is the map of the world (a part of it) loading really really slowly. The resolution is low, I can't zoom in and see strees, road, etc. Basically, everything is just pixelated, and when I zoom in the map doesnt even load, I can only see the grid.

I tried many things, yet nothing works. Any suggestions?

- I checked my API key many times and even generated a new one.
- I did restrict my key.
- I granted all the required permissions.

[image: This is my app, when I zoom in, it stays pixelated]

I'm pretty sure that my code is fine, but i'll post it anyway.

```
//The map code
        public void LoadMap()
        {
            if (IsGoogleApiAvailabe())
            {
                MapFragment mMapFragment = MapFragment.NewInstance();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.Add(Resource.Id.fragment_container, mMapFragment);
                fragmentTransaction.Commit();
                mMapFragment.GetMapAsync(this);
            }
        }
```

```
//Manifest File
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
          android:versionCode="1" 
          android:versionName="1.0" 
          package="com.example.android.porject">
  <permission
         android:name="com.example.android.PCP.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
         android:protectionLevel="signature" />

  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="27" />

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.example.android.PCP.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

  <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>


  <application 
    android:allowBackup="true" 
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" 
    android:label="P.C.P" 
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" 
    android:supportsRtl="true" 
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <meta-data
      android:name = "com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
      android:value = "@string/GoogleKey" />
    <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

  </application>
</manifest>
```

What am i missing?

Comment: have you looked for messages related to mapping in the log output / application output window?

Comment: Wow. I just looked for it, this is what I got:

Comment: Authorization failure. Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start for how to correctly set up the map.
In the Google Developer Console (https://console.developers.google.com)
Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.
Ensure that the following Android Key exists:
API Key: **ceonsored**

Comment: By the way, my key is for Maps SDK for Android.

Comment: @Jason it seems like my meta-data is wrong. Which ones should I use?

Comment: You have no idea how much I thank you. Apparently during those 2 crazy days I have been using a wrong SHA-1.
Don't do this mistake!
I took my SHA-1 from an Android Studio Google Maps project. In the debug output window of VS I was given the right fingerprint.

Comment: awesome, I'm glad you figured it out

Comment: @Daniel Reyhanian, please post your solution as an answer and accept it so this questions gets marked as answered. Helps other searching for questions to help on so they don't waste time on questions that are answered. Thanks!

Comment: @jgoldberger-MSFT For some reason the system says that "We are longer accepting answers from this account. 

Could you also please post this as an answer? I will verify it:::

Apparently this whole time I have been using a wrong SHA-1.

Don't do this mistake: 
For some reason, the SHA-1 from the Android Studio Google Maps project was wrong- as explained in most of the Google Maps tutorials as the easiest way to get this fingerprint. 

The alternative ways to get the fingerprint:

Comment: 1.In the debug output window of VS, while debugging the application, search for "keystore certificate" right under those instructions in the output window:
Authorization failure. Please see developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start for how to correctly set up the map. In the Google Developer Console (console.developers.google.com) Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled. Ensure that the following Android Key exists:


2.I haven't tried this option yet, but use the following command to get the fingerprint::
keytool -list -v -keystore mystore.keystore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this whole time I have been using a wrong SHA-1. Don't do this mistake: For some reason, the SHA-1 from the Android Studio Google Maps project was wrong- as explained in most of the Google Maps tutorials as the easiest way to get this fingerprint. The alternative ways to get the fingerprint:

1. In the debug output window of VS, while debugging the application, search for "keystore certificate" right under those instructions in the output window: Authorization failure. Please see developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start for how to correctly set up the map. In the Google Developer Console (console.developers.google.com) Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled. Ensure that the following Android Key exists: {KEY}".
2. I haven't tried this option yet, but use the following command to get the fingerprint::keytool -list -v -keystore mystore.keystore